# Not enough memory to row bind two large datasets

Tags: r

I am trying to row bind two very big datasets, but I lack sufficient RAM memory.

What I tried is:

1. Read each dataset via `A <- fread("A.csv"); B <- fread("B.csv")`
2. Run `gc()` to free the memory.
3. Merge the two with `AB <- rbindlist(list(A, B), fill = TRUE)`

Then I get the error that I don't have enough RAM: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.6 Mb`.

Note that the two datasets have different column names, that is why I need to use `fill = TRUE`. Also, the dataset have both numerical and character values.

How can I merge both without running into RAM issues?

---

**Edit**

- I have 32GB of RAM.
- Dataset `A` is 357896 x 11873
- Dataset `B` is 64979 x 877
- All columns from `A` are different from dataset `B`
  [image]

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How large is your data? How many columns are distinct? In other words: *does the entire data actually fit in memory twice?* (Once for each original copy, once for the merged data).

Comment: @KonradRudolph see my edit

Comment: So, in a nutshell, the data might simply not fit into memory: *at a minimum*, your combined data is 16 GiB in size in memory (but probably more). When merging the data, R needs to create a second copy of your data. This can, quite simply, not work. You can try merging columns individually (adding columns from `B` to `A` in-place in a loop, and deleting the column from `B` after adding it to `A`). However, even that might still fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the combined dataset can fit into memory, you could try combining the tables in a  CSV via `fwrite` with `append = TRUE`.

```
library(data.table)
fwrite(
  rbindlist(
    list(
      fread("A.csv", nrows = 1L),
      fread("B.csv")
    ),
    fill = TRUE
  )[-1],
  "AB.csv"
)
fwrite(
  fread("A.csv"),
  "AB.csv",
  append = TRUE
)
# maybe restart R here
AB <- fread("AB.csv", fill = TRUE)
```